# Outsource the /boot onto a SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

Now I'm going to buy me a new Laptop. So this Computer uses a 500 GB 7200rpm SATA Hybrid Hard Drive with 4 GB SSD, so my question is:

Is it possible to just use the SSD for /boot? Does  it reduce the booting time significantly?

Thx for Answers!!

Answer (score 3):

[Hybrid Drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive) using conventinal platters combinded with a (small) SSD have the advantage of using the SSD as a rather large non-volatile and fast cache for improving data transfer rates. Access to this SSD part is done entirely by the hard-disk's firmware.

> Because of this there is no way to partition the drive to exclusively use the SSD as a /boot partition.

Neverthelesss there is some benefit as compared to a conventional drive. All disk access  can be cached by the SSD. Other than a combination of a convential hard drive together with a separate SSD you will (in theory) then also have a better access to data that would not be stored on the SSD.

Comment: Does the hard drive still manage data across partitions? So no matter how you partition the drive, the SSD will contain the most-accessed files?

Comment: Depending on the firmware the hybrid drive will likely cache across partitions too.